# Moving data from AWS Aurora MySQL to another AWS Aurora MySQL with AWS Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-aurora

I have an AWS Aurora MySQL database on my production environment, and a separate AWS Aurora MySQL database on my performance environment. Periodically, I'll create a copy the production database, and use the copy as my database in my Performance environment, switching out the old performance database and replacing it with the new one.

Does AWS Glue provide the ability to move data from one Aurora MySQL database to another Aurora MySQL database? Could I use it to periodically (maybe once a week) copy over data from the Prod database to the Perf database? Also, if this is possible, would I be able to selectively copy data over from the prod MySQL, without necessarily losing data that was only added on the perf MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May I suggest not to use Glue for a full copy of a database, but AWS DMS (Database Migration Service) instead.

You can do very quick 1-to-1 migrations between two databases with DMS. You spin a DMS instance (Linux server, low cost, turn it off when not in use), set up a source and a target endpoint, and a replication task, and you're good to go.

Here is a guide you can follow: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/sbs/chap-rdsoracle2aurora.html

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! AWS DMS sounds like it'll fit my use case, I'll definitely look into using it.